# How to set interpreter to 'none' for gplotmatrix's legend?

Tags: matlab

The legend names have some underscore "_" characters in it and the legends became weird with subscripts due to TEX conversion. I tried to disable interpreter using the code below but still failed to do so.

```
% first try 
gplotmatrix(x,[],group)
legend(gca,'Interpreter','none')

%second try
[~,ax,~]=gplotmatrix(x,[],group)
set(ax,'Interpreter','none')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the `legend` handle with `findobj` and set the property:

```
hl = findobj(gcf,'Tag','legend')
set(hl,'Interpreter','none')
```

The parent axes handle is not returned in any of the outputs of `gplotmatrix`, it seems.